# Integral equality

Tags: measure-theory, functions

I have recently started studying function spaces (namely Lorentz endpoint spaces).

Let $\varphi:[0; \infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative concave function such that $\varphi(x)=x\Leftrightarrow x=0$ and let $(R, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. We define functions $\mu_f(t)=\mu(\{x\in R; |f(x)|>t\})$ and $f^*(t)=\inf\{\lambda\geq0; \mu_f(\lambda)\leq t\}$.
We also define $||f||_{\Lambda_\varphi}=\int_0^\infty \! f^*(t)\, \mathrm{d}\varphi(x)$.

These definitions are followed by this statement:

The Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral is well-defined because $\varphi$ is non-decreasing (I understand this). Furthermore, since $\varphi$ is non-negative and concave, it may be represented as the integral of a non-negative, non-increasing function, say $\phi$, on $(0,\infty)$. Hence the integral may be rewritten in the form $||f||_{\Lambda_\varphi}=||f||_{L^\infty}\varphi(0_+) + \int_0^\infty \! f^*(t)\phi(t)\, \mathrm{d}t$.

Hard as I tried, I can't prove the last equality. I tried using per-partes for L-S integral but that led me nowhere. A bit further, there is a remark that implies that $\phi$ should be equal to  the derivative of $\varphi$ (which exists a.e. since $\varphi$ is monotone). Sadly, it didn't help me. We didn't cover much such things in the measure theory course I took, so I feel lost right now.

I would be really grateful if you could help me make it clear. Thanks a lot!